# How do I add an event listener in an IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am making an IntelliJ plugin and would like to add a `RefactoringEventListener` to it. I implemented the class, but the documentation is unclear on how I register it. Do I have to add it somewhere in plugin.xml?

Comment: This question does not ask anyone to recommend any off-site resource, it asks how to use the IntelliJ IDEA plugin API. It's perfectly on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RefactoringEventListener` has `REFACTORING_EVENT_TOPIC` topic, which is the entry point for the listener. You can use it like:

```
project.getMessageBus().connect(Disposable)
    .subscribe(RefactoringEventListener.REFACTORING_EVENT_TOPIC, new MyListener())
```